# html/css individual radio button icon

Tags: html, css

I want to individualise the icons of each radio button with FontAwesome icons. So far I thought, I can set a placeholder for the indicator class and define individual icons during the ID´tag. Usually it overwrites all parameters.

Each of them will represent a menu slide, which basically slides out. To avoid unnecessary slide- in and out coding, I thought to simply use radio buttons instead of toggles.

View the example in full page mode to get the whole idea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #e6e7ee;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
  
  .radiogroup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #ecf0f3;
    border-top-right-radius: 35px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow:
    6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
  }
  
  .wrapper-first{
    margin-top: 150px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }

  .wrapper-last{
    margin-top: 310px;
  }
  
  .state {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1e-5;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .label {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #394a56;
  }
  
  .indicator {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .indicator::before,
  .indicator::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Fontawesome;
    font-size: 25px;
    content:"\f013";
  }
  
  .indicator::before {
    box-shadow:
      -4px -2px 4px 0px #d1d9e6,
      4px 2px 8px 0px #fff;
  }
  
  .indicator::after {
    background-color: #ecf0f3;
    box-shadow:
      -4px -2px 4px 0px #fff,
      4px 2px 8px 0px #d1d9e6;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out, transform .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .state:checked ~ .label .indicator::after {
    transform: scale3d(.975, .975, 1) translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .state:focus ~ .label .text {
    transform: translate3d(8px, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .indicator:hover {
    color: #3498db;
  }

  #radio-info{
      content: "\f129";
  }

</style>

<body>
    <!--------------- SVG ----------------->
    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <!--------------- NAV ----------------->
    <div class="radiogroup">
        <div class="wrapper-first">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="a" value="a">
            <label class="label" for="a">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="b" value="b">
            <label class="label" for="b">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="c" value="c">
            <label class="label" for="c">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="d" value="d">
            <label class="label" for="d">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="e" value="e">
            <label class="label" for="e">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="f" value="f">
            <label class="label" for="f">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-last">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="radio-info" value="radio-info">
            <label class="label" for="radio-info">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) to achieve that.

```
  #a ~ .label .indicator::after, #a ~ .label .indicator::before {
    content: "\f015"; 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #e6e7ee;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
  
  .radiogroup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #ecf0f3;
    border-top-right-radius: 35px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 35px;
    box-shadow:
    6px 6px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -6px -6px 10px white;
  }
  
  .wrapper-first{
    margin-top: 150px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    margin: 20px 0;
  }

  .wrapper-last{
    margin-top: 310px;
  }
  
  .state {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1e-5;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  .label {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #394a56;
  }
  
  .indicator {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .indicator::before,
  .indicator::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Fontawesome;
    font-size: 25px;
    content:"\f013";
  }
  
  .indicator::before {
    box-shadow:
      -4px -2px 4px 0px #d1d9e6,
      4px 2px 8px 0px #fff;
  }
  
  .indicator::after {
    background-color: #ecf0f3;
    box-shadow:
      -4px -2px 4px 0px #fff,
      4px 2px 8px 0px #d1d9e6;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out, transform .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .state:checked ~ .label .indicator::after {
    transform: scale3d(.975, .975, 1) translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .state:focus ~ .label .text {
    transform: translate3d(8px, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .indicator:hover {
    color: #3498db;
  }

  #a ~ .label .indicator::after, #a ~ .label .indicator::before {
    content: "\f015"; 
  }

  #b ~ .label .indicator::after, #b ~ .label .indicator::before {
      content: "\f016"; 
  }

  #c ~ .label .indicator::after, #c ~ .label .indicator::before {
    content: "\f017"; 
  }

  #d ~ .label .indicator::after, #d ~ .label .indicator::before {
    content: "\f018"; 
  }

</style>

<body>
    <!--------------- SVG ----------------->
    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

    <!--------------- NAV ----------------->
    <div class="radiogroup">
        <div class="wrapper-first">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="a" value="a">
            <label class="label" for="a">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="b" value="b">
            <label class="label" for="b">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="c" value="c">
            <label class="label" for="c">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="d" value="d">
            <label class="label" for="d">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="e" value="e">
            <label class="label" for="e">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="f" value="f">
            <label class="label" for="f">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-last">
            <input class="state" type="radio" name="app" id="radio-info" value="radio-info">
            <label class="label" for="radio-info">
                <div class="indicator"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>

</html>
```